How to fix FFmpeg amix and adelay messing up sound quality of MP3 audio?
I am trying to add a background sound effect to an input MP3 file. The FFmpeg command works, but the problem is that the quality of the resulting output mp3 file gets worse and worse every time I repeat the command using different adelay value.
Could someone please help me with this? What can I add or remove from the FFmpeg commands so that the original sound quality is preserved?
This is my MP3 command:
c:\ffmpeg.exe -i input.original.mp3 -i bells_church.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=1[a];[1:a]volume=1[b];[b]adelay=delays=2s:all=true[c];[a][c]amix=inputs=2:duration=first:normalize=0" -c:v copy -c:a libmp3lame -y output.mp3

After running this command first time, I replace the original mp3 file with the output mp3 file and then I repeat the command with a different adelay value, like:
c:\ffmpeg.exe -i input.original.mp3 -i bells_church.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=1[a];[1:a]volume=1[b];[b]adelay=delays=5s:all=true[c];[a][c]amix=inputs=2:duration=first:normalize=0" -c:v copy -c:a libmp3lame -y output.mp3

Then I repeat the process a couple more times, a different adelay value each time. By the time I have done this 3-5 times, the quality of the audio MP3 is noticeably worse.
Listening to the resulting output MP3 is like listening to a tape which was rubbed on stone a couple of times
Sometimes I have to change the sound effect MP3 file, so I cannot put all the adelay values in a single long command. Plus that will also confuse me too much and I might end up doing mistakes.

I have uploaded the original mp3 file here: https://tbrjar.com/audiotest/input.original.mp3
The output file is here: https://tbrjar.com/audiotest/output.mp3
The sound effect file is here: https://tbrjar.com/audiotest/bells_church.mp3


MP3 is a lossy codec and what you're observing is called generational loss. The filters are irrelevant. Use a lossless codec for intermediate outputs and only encode to MP3 for the final output.
So, -c:a flac output.flac for all intermediate outputs and -c:a libmp3lame -y output.mp3 for the final output.

you are wonderful! I have read your other ffmpeg related answers on this website and I think also on stackoverflow, and have learned a lot from you. You truly are wonderful! Many Many Thanks
